# Detect Line Number of Occurrences In CSV File

Tags: java, parsing, csv, file-io, conditional-statements

How would you obtain the line number from a file that is being parsed using the OpenCSV library where a certain condition occurs? I am looking to warn the user with the line number within their CSV file wherever there is a potentially erroneous value detected on that line.

Here is a piece of code from where I parse the file into a string array:

```
try 
{
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',');

    // Reads the complete file into list of tokens.
    List<String[]> rowsAsTokens = null;

    try 
    {
        rowsAsTokens = reader.readAll();
    } 

    for(String[] row: rowsAsTokens) 
    {
        //Check for conditions within CSV file
    }

    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to raise a  int linecounter by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
   int line = 0;
   for(String[] row: rowsAsTokens) 
   {

        //Check for conditions within CSV file
        if (isErro) {
            String errMsg = "error in line: " + line;
            // output errrMsg;
        }
        line++;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

set up a counter for your loop to count the line number as you parse the CSV.

```
try 
{
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',');

    // Reads the complete file into list of tokens.
    List<String[]> rowsAsTokens = null;

    int lineNum = 0;

    try 
    {
        rowsAsTokens = reader.readAll();
    } 

    for(String[] row: rowsAsTokens) 
    {
        lineNum++; // increment the line number
        //Check for conditions within CSV file
        if (ERRONEOUS VALUE) {
            // save the lineNum. possibly to an array or a string. whatever you need
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```